# Объяснить как работает рекурсивная функция в js

Tags: javascript

```
function pow(x,y) {
    if(y === 1) {
        return x;
    }else{
        return x * pow(x,y-1);
    }
}
console.log(pow(5,3)); //125
```

Здраствуйте, изучаю js, возникла проблема с рекурсией. На данном примере код который возводить число в степень с помощью рекурсии. Я не понимаю как работает так что "x" умножается столько "y" раз. Можете подробно объяснить как происходит это умножение

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: бесполезная функция, ужасная реализация, просто породия на возведение в степень. А отрицательная степень, а дробные значения степени? `let pow=(x,n)=>x**n;`, `let {pow}=Math;`.

Answer (score 0):

Любая правильная рекурсия имеет `условие выхода`, и Ваша рекурсия тоже при `y === 1` произойдет ее завершение (синяя стрелочка) Так же рекусивная функция по определению вызывает себя (красная стрелочка) как видно аргумент `y` уменьшается на `1` поэтому и получается что функция выполнится `y` раз, т.е. когда сработает `y === 1` вызова `pow(x, y-1)` больше не произойдет, вернется результат исполнения функции (переданный аргументом в ее параметр) и отработает `console.log`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]